# Org-mode: Getting errors when auto-saving after refiling

Tags: org-mode

I wanted Emacs to automatically save all buffers after I refiled something, so I followed the bottom-most comment from [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/477/how-do-i-automatically-save-org-mode-buffers) and used

```
(advice-add 'org-refile :after 'org-save-all-org-buffers)
```

It works great when the only thing I need to do is refile.

However, if I try to `org-copy` something (which does an `org-refile` under the hood), or use a custom function which uses `org-refile` in some way, I get the following error:

```
Wrong number of arguments: #[nil "ÀÁ!\210ÂÃÄ\"\210ÅÆ!\203^R^@Ç \210ÀÈ!\207" 
[message "Saving all Org-mode buffers..." save-some-buffers t 
#[nil "ÀÁ!\207" [derived-mode-p org-mode] 2] featurep org-id org-id-locations-save 
"Saving all Org-mode buffers... done"] 
3 ("c:/Users/wiuah/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20160801/org.elc" . 620558) nil], 4
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: How about creating a new custom function that calls `org-refile` and then calls `org-save-all-org-buffers` instead of placing an `advice` on a commonly used function?  Sure, you can still play around with `advice` and put in exceptions and additional arguments, but why go through the trouble?

Comment: @lawlist If you can provide a working function that takes the same parameters as `org-refile` but also saves the buffers after copying/moving, I'll probably accept it.

Comment: `(defun my-org-refile (&optional goto default-buffer rfloc msg) (interactive "P") "Doc-string." (org-refile goto default-buffer rfloc msg) (org-save-all-org-buffers))`  If you really want to learn how to do this with `advice` and create exceptions so that `org-refile` can be used by other functions without throwing an error, then by all means leave the question open for now.  Almost everyone except me loves `advice` -- I use it very sparingly.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue. The refile `advice` used to work but stopped at some point. A similar error reported [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/helm-projectile/issues/51) suggested a solution that works for me:

```el
(advice-add 'org-refile :after
        (lambda (&rest _)
        (org-save-all-org-buffers)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar advice is described [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7910#issuecomment-493258698).  It only saves the buffer in question:

```
(defun save-after-capture-refile ()
  (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer org-capture-last-stored-marker)
    (save-buffer)))
(advice-add 'org-capture-refile :after 'save-after-capture-refile)
```